# Rest service doesn't work in apk file : ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

In my ionic application rest service doesn't work when i create apk file using below code

> adb install -r platforms/android/build/output/apk/android-debug.apk

If i run application in browser:

```
ionic serve
```

then its work file

If I run application in mobile using below code

> ionic run -l

then its work fine..
But once i create apk file and install in mobile then service does't work..

how can solve this problem??
please help

Answer (score 2):

The most probable reason is that you don't have `cordova-whitelist` plugin. The newer version of cordova/ ionic requires for you to use this plugin

**Steps:**

1. Install the plugin

   ```
   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
   ```
2. Update your `config.xml` to whitelist the allowed urls:

   ```
   <allow-navigation href="*" />
   ```

Refer https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist for details

Comment: I already added..I tried again..And I got this Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on android.
Plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" already installed on browser.

Answer (score 1):

The rest web service is hosted locally on a development server or PC and running on a address like e.g. http://localhost:8888. Once compiling to an APK it will also be expecting the service address which obviously is not on the device itself.

Therefore you need to host the REST service locally on a development server or PC using a WIFI enabled network exposing the PC's IIS or Apache (which ever one you are using) or you can use cloud hosting and reference the newly created API address in the app's source before compiling the APK.

This **[ARTICLE](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)** provides a good explanation between the difference of `ionic serve` and `run` variances

Comment: we have hosted our service on Apache server and we are able to access the serveices using the hosted address.